# Is this contact form secure?

Tags: php, security, ajax, form

I have the following contact form, using PHP, JS and a bit of Ajax. I want to make sure that it is secure.

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    ob_start();
        if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_POST['token']))
        {
            if($_SESSION['token'] != $_POST['token'])
            {
                $response = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['token'] = "";

                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];

                $to = "email@here.com";
                $subject = "New Message From: $name";
                $message = "$message";

                $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'From: '.$email . "\r\n";
                $mailed = ( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) );

                if( isset($_POST['ajax']))
                    $response = ($mailed) ? "1" : "0";
                else
                    $response = ($mailed) ? "<h2>Success!</h2>" : "<h2>Error! There was a problem with sending.</h2>";

                echo $response;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Form data error!";
        }
    ob_flush();
    die();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

    <head>
        <title>Contact us | Website Name</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <?php include ("assets/includes/header.inc"); ?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header id="headerWrapper">
            <div id="headerContent">

                <div id="headerLogo"><!--Logo-->
                    <?php include ("assets/includes/header-logo.inc"); ?>
                </div>

                <nav><!--Main Menu-->
                    <ul id="mainMenu">
                        <?php include ("assets/includes/menu.inc"); ?>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </header>

        <!--Header (small screens only)-->
        <?php include ("assets/includes/second-header.inc"); ?>

        <div id="page"><!--Page Container-->

            <div id="contactPage" class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">

                    <!--Contact Form-->
                    <?php
                        $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
                        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
                    ?>
                    <form id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post" name="contactForm">
                        <input id="token" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />

                        <div class="name">
                            <label>Your Name</label>
                            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="email">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="message">
                            <label>Message</label>
                            <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>

                    </form>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {

                        /* stop form from submitting normally */
                        event.preventDefault();

                        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
                        var $form = $(this),
                            $submit = $form.find('button[id="submit"]'),
                            token_value = $form.find('input[id="token"]').val(),
                            name_value = $form.find('input[id="name"]').val(),
                            email_value = $form.find('input[id="email"]').val(),
                            message_value = $form.find('textarea[id="message"]').val(),
                            url = $form.attr('action');

                        /* send the data using post */
                        var posting = $.post(url, {
                            token : token_value,
                            name : name_value,
                            email : email_value,
                            message : message_value,
                            ajax : 1
                        });

                        posting.done(function(data) {
                            $form.find('span.error').remove();

                            if (data == "1") {

                                /*Change the button text.*/
                                $submit.text('Sent. Thank You!');
                                $submit.addClass("sent");
                                $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                            } else {
                                $submit.after('<span style="display: inline-block; padding: 20px 5px; color: #bd3d3d" class="error">Failed to send the message, please try again later.</span>');
                                /*Change the button text.*/
                                $submit.text('Try Again');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    </script>

                    <!--Contact Details Section-->
                    <div id="contactDetails">

                        <div>
                            <h3><strong>Contact Details</strong></h3>
                                <br>
                            <p><strong>Telephone:</strong> +44 00 0000000</p>
                            <p><strong>Email:</strong> email@email.com</p>

                            <!--Phone contact buttons-->
                            <div class="hidden">
                                <a href="tel:0044000000000">Tap to call us</a>
                                <a href="sms:0044000000000">Tap to send us a SMS</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--Social Icons-->
                        <br><div class="socialbar">
                            <p><strong>Find us on:</strong></p>
                            <a href="#" target="blank" class="icon-facebook"></a>
                            <a href="#" target="blank" class="icon-linkedin"></a>
                            <a href="#" target="blank" class="icon-twitter"></a>
                            <a href="#" target="blank" class="icon-youtube"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Footer-->
            <footer id="footer">
                <?php include ("assets/includes/footer.inc"); ?>
            </footer>

        </div><!--The End Of The Page-->
        <!--Scripts Links-->
        <?php include ("assets/includes/scripts.inc"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have quotes around your integers?

Answer (score 3):

No, I've noticed several issues.

Make sure the stuff in `assets/includes/` isn't world readable.

e.g. is it possible to view this code by going to `www.example.com/assets/includes/second-header.inc` (substituting in your domain name of course)?

Also, don't use `rand()` to generate tokens for secure use. `rand()` will generate predictable values that can be guessed by an attacker.

[The manual](https://www.php.net/rand) states:

> Caution
> This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) instead.

You need cryptographically secure values for use as tokens.

Also, make sure that the `email` you are entering in the headers

```
  $headers .= 'From: '.$email . "\r\n";
```

has new lines and carriage return characters stripped from it to prevent [Email Header Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection).

Otherwise you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

The form seems to be OK, but mixing all of the code in one file is not a best-practice.

**UPDATE**

Some tips on code separation:

- I would suggest using any template system for html/php code
  separation. For example Smarty.
- Also, it would be easier for you to
  maintain your code if you follow the MVC pattern.
- Moving the js code
  to a separate file and loading it would also separate you js logic
  from template.
- As @SilverlightFox mentioned, make sure you protect you .inc file. This could be done like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968901/folders-protection-in-php/13969167#13969167) answer of mine.

Some other tips:

- I would rather use `$token = md5(time());` than `$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));`
- Using `ob_start(); ... ob_end_flush();` functions is often confusing as it prevents other files from rendering any output.
- **Always** use curly brackets for if constructions: `if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) { ... } else { ... }`. Otherwise you might confuse the logic/flow of the application when you'll be re factoring your own code like in 6 month, for example.

Comment: A note on MD5: Since the 90s issues have been found with that algorithm. Do not use it for anything else than interfacing with legacy systems. To checksum something, the SHA family is often a better solution. To scramble some secret, use a key-stretching function like bcrypt. Using `md5(time())` as a token produces predictable tokens, and can issue multiple identical tokens – this is most obvious if you think of it as a concurrency bug. This is actually far worse in any respect than `uniqid rand`. Otherwise, nice review: +1

Comment: @amon, this is a contact form, not a bank vault. I suppose this would be enough.